# Instead of image download it is opening in the another tab

Tags: javascript

The image is opening in another tab while when it is clicked

```
<a href="~/images/ProofPics/@idproofrow.ItemArray.GetValue(i + 2)" title="Download Image" style="text-decoration:underline;"><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i> Image Download</a>
```

Comment: give download inside anchor <a download href="..">

Comment: it is working thank u

Comment: And why would a regular anchor download anything ?

Comment: then which one we can use

Comment: @VinodLouis worth noticing this would only work in html5 browsers

Comment: is it possible to show the image as well as download the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `download` attribute in your `<a>` tag.

```
<a href="/image.jpg" download>Download</a>
```

Though keep in mind that this **only support the modern browsers**. You can check this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp) for the supported browsers available